# Calling removeElement on EXTRA_LAZY collection is loading all elements

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

Using Symfony's API-Platform, with Doctrine, I am hitting a problem that's so bad that I can't believe it exists and not fixed/ignored by Doctrine's team for years.

I have a `Post` and a `PostCategory` entity, regular Doctrine entities. They have a many-to-many relation using a `post_to_category` table.
When I assign one/more categories to a `Post` and save, everything is okay, but when I edit a `Post` and remove one of the assigned categories, `Doctrine` will load all the `Post`s for that category before de-association. That is hundred of thousands of `Post`s. And of course we're running in OOM errors.

The problem is described in details at https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8739

I am trying to find a workaround to this problem so I can continue working on this project, but nothing from what I've tried so far is working.

In the above github issue, they advertise a workaround, which has some typos and can't be applied in the current version anymore. Or I wasn't able to.

Since the project is using API-Platform, I asked on the slack channel about the issue and I was told that using a state processor would allow me to avoid this issue by removing the associations early-on. Unfortunately, that does not work because the state processor already receives processed data, so basically I get the OOM before I hit the state processor.

This is a complete mess.

I refuse to believe I am the only one hitting this problem.
How do I solve it?

Comment: Indeed it's a doctrine issue, I hope it will be solved soon, maybe thanks to you because you reopen the pull request. But according to the documentation : "removeElement directly issued DELETE queries to the database from version 2.4.0 to 2.7.0. This circumvents the flush operation and might run outside a transactional boundary if you don't create one yourself. We consider this a critical bug in the assumption of how the ORM works and reverted removeElement EXTRA_LAZY behavior in 2.7.1."